# How to upload .gz files into Google Big Query?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-bigquery

I have an idea of a 90 GB `.csv` file that I want to make on my local computer and then upload into Google BigQuery for analysis. I create this file by combining thousands of smaller `.csv` files into 10 medium-sized files and then combining those medium-sized files into the 90 GB file, which I then want to move to GBQ. I am struggling with this project because my computer keeps crashing from memory issues. From [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v9bGNHqyA6M) video I understood that I should first transform the medium-sized `.csv` files (about 9 GB each) into `.gz` files (about 500MB each), and then upload those `.gz` files into Google Cloud Storage. Next, I would create an empty Table (in Google BigQuery / Datasets) and then append all of those files to the created Table. The issue I am having is finding some kind of tutorial about how to do this or and documentation of how to do this. I am new to the Google Platform so maybe this is a very easy job that can be done with 1 click somewhere, but all I was able to find was from the video that I linked above. Where can I find some help or documentation or tutorials or videos on how people do this? Do I have the correct idea on the workflow? Is there some better way (like using some downloadable GUI to upload stuff)?

Comment: You don't need to combine the files into one big file. Just create your dataset and table and use python, java, ruby or go to process each file (or a group of files) and load them to bigquery. I have done something similar with python very recently. Let me know if you need a primer.

Comment: @Abdou an outline of what you're discussing would have been helpful for this question i think. From the given answer it's not clear how to load a gz file from google storage into bigquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the instructions here:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/bq-command-line-tool#creatingtablefromfile

As Abdou mentions in a comment, you don't need to combine them ahead of time. Just gzip all of your small CSV files, upload them to a GCS bucket, and use the "bq.py load" command to create a new table. Note that you can use a wildcard syntax to avoid listing all of the individual file names to load.

The --autodetect flag may allow you to avoid specifying a schema manually, although this relies on sampling from your input and may need to be corrected if it fails to detect in certain cases.

Comment: where in that page does it refer to gz files specifically?

Comment: It isn't mentioned specifically, although either uncompressed or compressed data is allowed. There are tradeoffs -- compressed data obviously uses less storage space (and transfer bandwidth), but parts of an individual file cannot be read in parallel. This page (linked from the one above) has a bit more information: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#loading_csv_data_into_a_new_table